# Using CSS to select dom elements to select a class name containing a number greater than X

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors

I was researching css attribute selectors to try and solve a problem of mine:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors

I have a bunch of dom elements which are all classed according to their depth in a json hierarchy (even though they are not nested in the DOM). So the dom might look like this:

```
<g class="node0">
<g class="node2">
<g class="node2">
<g class="node1">
<g class="node3">
```

I want to write a selector that targets g nodes with a class of node2 or higher. Is there a way to do this with pure css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[class^=node]:not(.node0):not(.node1) {
   // styles here
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zfJS)

Comment: Beat me to it :> Was just adding a fiddle to demonstrate. http://jsfiddle.net/8zfJS/

Comment: @DanSaltmer thanks but i have made fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3GNNZ/ I added your one.

Comment: Ah - but what if you wanted to select all nodes greater than 1 (so not zero or one), or say, greater than 6. Can css handle a mathematical range or > operator